# How to print dictionary key value pairs only after updating all items?

Tags: python

I have got a list of jobs ids with ten of thousands of items called "result"

i need to loop over this list get specific data for each job , i need to add those variables to a dictionary and then print the key value pairs when the dictionary update has been completed
and sorted by key

this is a shorten version of the code

```
jobs_dict = {}
for job_index in result:
    application_name = get_app_name(id)
    job_content = get_job_content(id)
    job_duration = get_job_duration(id)
    if  job_duration not not in jobs_dict.keys():
        jobs_dict.update( {job_duration : [job_content,application_name]} )
        for key, value in sorted(composite_prob_dict.items()):
            print(key, value)
```

my issue is that i need to print the key value pairs sorted by key, but i want to print the key value pairs
only after that all key value pairs has been added to the dictinary since i need to print the key value pairs sorted by keys

if i am printing the key value pairs i see the keys in the process of updating ,i want to print the entire dictionary
after all items has been updated ,sorted by key

here is a few lines of script output of course this is just the first lines its continues
as the key value pairs is added to the dictionary

```
(100.78492568380443, ['204181', '435882'])
------------------------------------------------------------------
(81.872401187661254, ['204183', '435884'])
------------------------------------------------------------------
(100.78492568380443, ['204181', '435882'])
------------------------------------------------------------------
(81.872401187661254, ['204183', '435884'])
------------------------------------------------------------------
(100.78492568380443, ['204181', '435882'])
------------------------------------------------------------------
(135.48969627632511, ['204184', '435885'])
```

when i am printing key value pairs,i want to get one tuple for key value pair once

and sorted by key i.e:

```
(81.872401187661254, ['204183', '435884'])
------------------------------------------------------------------
(100.78492568380443, ['204181', '435882'])
------------------------------------------------------------------
(135.48969627632511, ['204184', '435885'])
```

in short what is the way to print the dictionary key value pairs only after all items has been added
and sorted by key? without duplicates and sorted ?

Answer (score 0):

Take this bit of code:

```
    for key, value in sorted(composite_prob_dict.items()):
        print(key, value)
```

and unindent it so that `for` lines up with the first `for` in your code. Currently it is indented so as to put it inside the loop, so it prints every time you do an update.

Comment: i have unindented ,but its hanging, probably because i have ten of thousands  of objects , is there a way to improve the code so it will work faster ?

Comment: While your code is still under development, it is best to test it with a subset of the data if you have lots. That way your testing will go more quickly, and also it makes it more feasible to check the output manually. With tens of thousands of entries, what hope have you of spotting a logic error?

Comment: Ah, now that is a completely different question. Ask a new question with that as the title, showing the revised code that fixes the scope of the loop. And please fix the code to show the code you are actually working with, not a retyped or redacted version. (1) The test `not not in` is a syntax error. (2) It's not clear how the value of `id` ever changes.